# Is it possible to have the final line of wrapped text behave like an inline-block element?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have a headline followed by an icon, arranged on the same line like so:

```
<div class="outer-container">
 <h1 class="article-header">Sample Short Headline</h1>
 <object class="link-svg" type="image/svg+xml" data="./resources/link.svg" width="30px" height="30px"></object>
</div>
```

[image]

I set both elements as inline block elements, which is how I get them to stay on the same line. If the headline is longer than one line, then the multiple lines of text take up the whole horizontal width, regardless of whether the text is inline-block.

This creates the unwanted behavior of the icon being pushed to the line below, even if there is plenty of available space on the last line of wrapped text:

[image]

Ideally, I would like the wrapped text to behave as if each word is an inline-block element, so that the link wraps along with the text like so:

[image]

Now I could literally do that, placing each word in it's own inline-block container so that is behaves this way, but that feels very hacky, and would have to be done manually for headlines of different lengths.

This seems like a simple feature, and I imagine there is a better solution involving some types of wrapping attributes. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Why not put the image INSIDE the heading?

Comment: @Paulie_D I didn't know that was possible. How would that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `display: inline;` to your heading text `h1` element, and the icon will stick to the last word.
Here's an example:

```css
h1 {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
 <h1 class="article-header">Sample Long Headline to See How it will behave with multiple lines</h1>
 <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="css-i6dzq1"><path d="M10 13a5 5 0 0 0 7.54.54l3-3a5 5 0 0 0-7.07-7.07l-1.72 1.71"></path><path d="M14 11a5 5 0 0 0-7.54-.54l-3 3a5 5 0 0 0 7.07 7.07l1.71-1.71"></path></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. And moving the icon depends on whether it is the last one in the line.

Comment: This works like a charm, is simple, and works regardless of the header length. Thanks so much!

Comment: This works like a charm )) As I said in the previous comment - this it doesn't work! Here is a simple example: [codepen](https://codepen.io/imhvost/pen/oNQXJBb). You at least test a little before accepting the answer.

Comment: Not only is it working for me, it's working in the very codepen you sent!

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the last word and image in a `<span>` and set `white-space: nowrap;`:

```css
.article-header span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="article-header">
  Sample Short Sample Short Sample
  <span>
    Headline
    <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
      <line x1="0" y1="10" x2="20" y2="10" stroke="currentColor"/>
      <line x1="10" y1="0" x2="10" y2="20" stroke="currentColor"/>
    </svg>
  </span>
</h1>
```

Comment: This solution works, but is essentially the same as the hacky solution I mentioned in my question that I was trying to avoid. It would require me to wrap the last line of every single headline that way, and so it is not responsive to different or changing headlines.